# How to apply radius to ApplicationWindow in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I had a question about how to trimming corners around the edges in **ApplicationWindow**, i tried to use clip, opacity and many standard methods of the qml language My Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.13

ApplicationWindow {
    id: loginPage
    visible: true
    opacity: 0.8
    x: 732; y:245
    width: 456; height: 529
    color: "#3C096C"
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
}
```

**Here is the result that I want to get:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to not try to make the `ApplicationWindow` itself have a radius, but to make it transparent and simply draw a rounded `Rectangle` as the first child.

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: loginPage
    visible: true
    x: 732; y:245
    width: 456; height: 529

    color: "transparent"
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle {
        color: "#3C096C"
        opacity: 0.8
        radius: 20
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a workaround, not a solution. Transparency cannot be supported, unexpected margins can confuse, as well as unexpected window behaveor.  Each item must be used in accordance with its intended purpose. I guess that @eyllanesc's solution is the right way.

Comment: @folibis, The fact that you like someone else's answer better is not a reason to downvote mine. This is not a "workaround" at all. My solution not only works, it's pretty much the same as the way QtQuick.Controls are implemented. If you want to customize a `Button`, you have a separate `background` and `contentItem` that are children of the `Button`. My solution is the same, I'm just showing how to define the `background` item.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use the method setMask() of QWindow:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QWindow>

class Utils: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    Q_INVOKABLE void applyRadius(QWindow *window, int radius){

        QRect r(QPoint(), window->geometry().size());
        QRect rb(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

        QRegion region(rb, QRegion::Ellipse);
        rb.moveRight(r.right());
        region += QRegion(rb, QRegion::Ellipse);
        rb.moveBottom(r.bottom());
        region += QRegion(rb, QRegion::Ellipse);
        rb.moveLeft(r.left());
        region += QRegion(rb, QRegion::Ellipse);
        region += QRegion(r.adjusted(radius, 0, -radius, 0), QRegion::Rectangle);
        region += QRegion(r.adjusted(0, radius, 0, -radius), QRegion::Rectangle);
        window->setMask(region);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Utils utils;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Utils", &utils);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.13

ApplicationWindow {
    id: loginPage
    visible: true
    opacity: 0.8
    x: 732; y:245
    width: 456; height: 529
    color: "#3C096C"
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    Component.onCompleted: ()=> Utils.applyRadius(loginPage, 20);
}
```